# How to simplify $(a-b)^2(y-x)+(b-a)(x-y)^2-(b-a)(x-y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to simplify the following?:

$(a-b)^2(y-x)+(b-a)(x-y)^2-(b-a)(x-y)$

I have performed the following, but I think what I have arrived at is not the final step:

$(b-a)((b-a)(y-x)+(x-y)^2-(x-y))$

$ (b-a)((b-a)(y-x)+(y-x)^2+(y-x))$

$ (b-a)((y-x)((b-a)+(y-x)+1)))$

$ (b-a)(y-x)(y+b-a-x+1)$

Comment: $(b-a)(y-x)(y+b-a-x+1)$ is the final step !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got $$(x-y)(a-b)\left(-(a-b)-(x-y)+1\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the signs and binomials right away:
$$(a-b)^2(y-x)+(b-a)(x-y)^2-(b-a)(x-y)=\\
-(b-a)^2(x-y)+(b-a)(x-y)^2-(b-a)(x-y)=\\
(b-a)(x-y)[-(b-a)+(x-y)-1]=\\
(b-a)(x-y)[x-y+a-b-1]=\\
(a-b)(x-y)(y-x-a+b+1).$$